# Show/hide an html element with hover selector

Tags: css, hover

I want to hide a div element on mouse over only using css.

```
<div>Stuff shown on hover</div>

div {
    display: block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: solid black;
}

div:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Why that doesn't work?

if I want to change -for example- the background instead it works just fine:

```
div:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Is not possible to hide/show the same element which I'm applying the hover selector?

http://jsfiddle.net/link01/TknA8/

Comment: the fiddle seems to be working. what are you trying to hide again

Comment: I put a wrong fiddle by mistake, try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why that doesn't work?

Isn't that obvious ...?

The Div element is displayed.

You move your mouse over it - which puts it in its `:hover` state.

You say that for its `:hover` state, the element is to be removed completely from the rendered output.

Since it is now "not there any more", the mouse can't still be over it.

Mouse not over it any more means, element is no more in `:hover` state.

What does your CSS say again for the element when it is not in its `:hover` state?

Ah yes, `display:block`.

OK, browser renders the element again.

Hey, what's that, that freaking mouse is over it?

Let's see, that means it has to be removed again ...

Answer (score 2):

When an element has its display set to none it doesn't exist in the layout and therefore can't be interacted with with the mouse.

Just add a wrapper around it:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="hidden">Stuff shown on hover</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cecAn/

Comment: In my example it would probably be better to hide the element with visibility: hidden, because, this would prevent the wrapper from collapsing if it didn't have a fixed height/width.